# Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin

Tags: maven, junit5, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm trying to run tests on Juni5 + Maven but the surefire plugin gives me an error, searching the internet was unsuccessful.

Also, I try to run my test using a suite.

I try to run the command `mvn clean -Dtest=SuiteTest test`

Error logs:

```
INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----------------------< OpbuAppium:OpbuAppium >------------------------
[INFO] Building OpbuAppium 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ OpbuAppium ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/andreygordienko/AutoMobile/msb_bpmobile/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ OpbuAppium ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/andreygordienko/AutoMobile/msb_bpmobile/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.0:compile (default-compile) @ OpbuAppium ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 202 source files to /Users/andreygordienko/AutoMobile/msb_bpmobile/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ OpbuAppium ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ OpbuAppium ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 25 source files to /Users/andreygordienko/AutoMobile/msb_bpmobile/target/test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M7:test (default-test) @ OpbuAppium ---
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/maven/surefire/api/testset/TestSetFailedException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0 (Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors (Class.java:2671)
 ...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.surefire.api.testset.TestSetFailedException
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass (SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass (ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass (ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass (ClassRealm.java:239)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0 (Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors (Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors (Class.java:2020)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forConstructorOf (InjectionPoint.java:245)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.create (ConstructorBindingImpl.java:115)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createUninitializedBinding (InjectorImpl.java:706)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding (InjectorImpl.java:930)
    ...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  9.294 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-05-15T15:07:07+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M7:test (default-test) on project OpbuAppium: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M7:test failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M7:test: org/apache/maven/surefire/api/testset/TestSetFailedException
...
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] : org.apache.maven.surefire.api.testset.TestSetFailedException
```

my POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

4.0.0
OpbuAppium
OpbuAppium
1.0-SNAPSHOT

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <hibernate-version>5.0.1.Final</hibernate-version>
    <aspectj.version>1.9.8</aspectj.version>
    <allure.version>2.13.2</allure.version>
    <junit.jupter.version>5.9.1</junit.jupter.version>
    <junit-platform-surefire-provider.version>1.3.2</junit-platform-surefire-provider.version>
    <allure-junit5.version>2.6.0</allure-junit5.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-java-commons</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-commandline</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.0</version>
        <type>maven-plugin</type>
    </dependency>


    <!--JUNIT 5 Dependencies-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.jupter.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.jupter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--Allure Reporting Dependencies-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-junit5</artifactId>
        <version>${allure-junit5.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                <argLine>
                    -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                </argLine>
                <systemProperties>
                    <property>
                        <name>junit.jupiter.extensions.autodetection.enabled</name>
                        <value>true</value>
                    </property>
                </systemProperties>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3.2</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                    <version>${junit.jupter.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <reportVersion>2.4.1</reportVersion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Has anyone encountered a similar error and how did you solve it?

Comment: First use the most recent version of maven-surefire-plugin (3.1.0 see https://maven.apache.org/plugins/) instead of an older Mxx one... second use BOM of JUnit Jupiter and don't add manually surefire-provider and engine to surefire as dependencies (handled by surefire automatically...)...

Comment: if delete  engine to surefire as dependencies, surefire run Junit4 and this engin not view @Test annotations

--- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0:test (default-test) @ OpbuAppium ---
[INFO] Using auto detected provider **org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider**

Comment: If not delete  <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>, maven error:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0:test (default-test) on project OpbuAppium: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0:test failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0:test: org/apache/maven/surefire/api/testset/TestSetFailedException

Comment: That looks weird... just try to use version 3.1.0 instead and retry...

Comment: OK i change this block, 
now:

"[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.1.0:test (default-test) @ OpbuAppium ---
[INFO] Using auto detected provider org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider
[INFO] " - 
But surefire not view @Test

Comment: I delete JUNIT 5 - block,
add only <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
and  -  <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
                <version>5.9.3</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement> - and all worked

Comment: BTW: If I see `surefire run Junit4` that means your imports on your tests are usually not correct... Do you use annotations of JUnit 4 or correctly of JUnit Jupiter?

Comment: Use JUnit Jupiter annotation

Comment: Based on the subject of using test suites I have my doubts... can you please share your full pom file and the source code of your test (fully)...